# Can you help me fix the error message I am getting on my code?

Tags: arduino

I have these two sets of code and they both run fine on their own, but when I am trying to merge them together I am getting a ton of error messages. I'm new to coding and don't really know a whole lot so I was wondering if someone could just quickly look it over and see what's wrong. The compiler is saying that there is an expected unqualified id before the '{' token at the bottom where I have the code for the pushbutton. However I have tried and removed this and then I get the same message but instead of '{' it says 'if'
Thank you very much
EDIT: I don't know what properly formatting an error message looks like but here is my attempt:

```
Complete_Code:69:1: error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token
  {
   ^
   exit status 1
   expected unqualified-id before '{' token
```

Here is the code in question

```cpp
int pinButton = 5;
#include <Servo.h>
int servo1Pin = 8;
Servo servo1;
#include <Servo.h>
#define mainArm 0
#define jib 1
#define bucket 2
#define slew 3

Servo servo[2];            //code used for attaching upto 4 servos
byte angle[2] = {90, 90};  // middle point for servo angle
byte potPin[2] = {A1, A2}; // input pins to attach your potentiometers
byte servoPin[2] = {7, 6};

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Starting DiggerCode.ino");
  for (byte n = 0; n < 4; n++) {
    servo[n].attach(servoPin[n]);
  }
  pinMode(pinButton, INPUT);
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT); //red LED
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT); // yellow LED
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT); // green LED
  servo1.attach(servo1Pin);
}

void loop() {
  readPotentiometers();
  moveServos();
  delay(10);
}

void readPotentiometers() {
  int potVal;
  for (byte n = 0; n < 4; n++) {
    potVal = analogRead(potPin[n]);
    if (potVal < 200) {    // dead zone for the joystick I used is 200 to 550.
      angle[n] += 1;
      if (angle[n] > 170) {
         angle[n] = 170;
      }
    }
    if (potVal > 550) {    // deadzone upper value
      angle[n] -= 1;
      if (angle[n] < 10) {
        angle[n] = 10;
      }
    }
  }
}

void moveServos() {
  for (byte n = 0; n < 4; n++) {
    servo[n].write(angle[n]);
  }
}

{
  int stateButton = digitalRead(pinButton); //read the state of the button
  if (stateButton == HIGH) { //if is pressed
    Serial.println("Switch = High");
    digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(12, LOW);
    digitalWrite(11, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(11, LOW);
    digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(10, LOW);
    delay(500);
    servo1.write(180);
    delay(1000);
    // Make servo go to 180 degrees
    servo1.write(90);
    delay(1000);
    servo1.write(180);
}
}
```

Comment: It will be more convenient if you add the full error msg in a formatted way

Comment: Check the braces of the last block of code (starting brace and ending brace). I think you missed something while typing your code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you dropped the first things of function definition for some reason.

Add function return type, name and arguments for example

```
void anImportedFunction()
```

Before the part starting from

```
{
  int stateButton = digitalRead(pinButton); //read the state of the button
```

You may also need to call the added function from somewhere.

Comment: What kind of an imported function should I use? something like void readstateButton ? My apologies I'm new to this and I don't know what kind of imported functions there are

Answer (score 0):

I looked through your code and edited, some unnecessary and missing parts.
I checked it, no more syntax errors. I think it must work.

```
#include <Servo.h>

#define mainArm 0
#define jib 1
#define bucket 2
#define slew 3

Servo servo1;
Servo servo[4]; //code used for attaching upto 4 servos

int pinButton = 5;
int servo1Pin = 8;           
byte angle[2] = {90, 90};  // middle point for servo angle
byte potPin[2] = {A1, A2}; // input pins to attach your potentiometers
byte servoPin[2] = {7, 6};

void setup() {
  
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Starting DiggerCode.ino");
  
  for (byte n = 0; n <= 4; n++) {
    servo[n].attach(servoPin[n]);
  }
  
  pinMode(pinButton, INPUT);
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT); //red LED
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT); // yellow LED
  pinMode(10, OUTPUT); // green LED
  servo1.attach(servo1Pin);
}

void loop() {
  readPotentiometers();
  moveServos();
  delay(10);
}

void readPotentiometers() {
  int potVal;
  for (byte n = 0; n <= 4; n++) {
    potVal = analogRead(potPin[n]);
    if (potVal < 200) {    // dead zone for the joystick I used is 200 to 550.
      angle[n] += 1;
      if (angle[n] > 170) {
         angle[n] = 170;
      }
    }
    if (potVal > 550) {    // deadzone upper value
      angle[n] -= 1;
      if (angle[n] < 10) {
        angle[n] = 10;
      }
    }
  }
}

void moveServos() {
  for (byte n = 0; n <= 4; n++) {
    servo[n].write(angle[n]);
  }
}

void Switch() //here instead of "Switch" you can use any function name you want
{
  int stateButton = digitalRead(pinButton); //read the state of the button
  if (stateButton == HIGH) { //if is pressed
    Serial.println("Switch = High");
    digitalWrite(12, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(12, LOW);
    digitalWrite(11, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(11, LOW);
    digitalWrite(10, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(10, LOW);
    delay(500);
    servo1.write(180);
    delay(1000);
    // Make servo go to 180 degrees
    servo1.write(90);
    delay(1000);
    servo1.write(180);
  }
}
```